# prev() and next() return no result

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

`prev()` and `next()` return no result, but `current()`, `end()` and `reset()` does as you can see here:

http://flamencopeko.net/songs_scans_skip_2.php
http://flamencopeko.net/songs_scans_skip_2.txt

```
<?php
   echo current($arrFiles);
?>
<br />prev: 
<?php
   echo prev($arrFiles);
?>
<br />next: 
<?php
   echo next($arrFiles);
?>
<br />end: 
<?php
   echo end($arrFiles);
?>
<br />reset: 
<?php
   echo reset($arrFiles);
?>
```

End goal is to make skip buttons change large scans. Some say it must be done in JS. I'm fine with both PHP and JS, but I completely fail to see how to write the needed functions.

---

This makes the array:

```
<?php
$arrFiles = array_diff(scandir("scans", 0), array(".", ".."));
$arrFiles = array_values($arrFiles);
$intCountFiles = count($arrFiles);
?>
```

Comment: Can you include the content of `$arrFiles` in your question? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. That content is on the page both as text and images. I also posted the code making the array below now.

Answer (score 4):

You call `prev` after you call `current`, the internal pointer in array will go out of the rang. It will not come back unless you call `reset` or `end`.

So after you have called `current`, the pointer point to `index 0`, then you called `prev`. The pointer went out of range, and returned `false`.

Then you called `next`, but the pointer was out of range, it could not move to next, so `next` also return `false`.

`next` acts like `prev`, once the pointer goes out of range, it will no come back,  unless you call `reset` or `end`;

See the zend source code blow, it explains that:

```
    ZEND_API int zend_hash_move_backwards_ex(HashTable *ht, HashPosition *pos)
    {
        HashPosition *current = pos ? pos : &ht->pInternalPointer;

        IS_CONSISTENT(ht);

        if (*current) {
            *current = (*current)->pListLast;
            return SUCCESS;
        } else
            return FAILURE;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. Now I feel even stupider than yesterday, but armed with more knowledge.

Comment: That did it srain. http://flamencopeko.net/songs_scans_skip_5.php :) Now I need to make the skip functions. You sure pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Never heard of the Zend API. Reading up on it now.

Comment: Not sure what question you're referring to. Most of the Zend stuff is very alien to me. But somewhat interesting. Thanks for the positive vibrations here again. Keeps me coding.

Comment: I got ajax to show a picture now. Here http://flamencopeko.net/ajax2/index.php. Now I probably need a for loop. Sources: http://flamencopeko.net/ajax2/index.txt, http://flamencopeko.net/ajax2/do_query.txt and http://flamencopeko.net/ajax2/ajax.js.

Comment: Do you have a related question about it?

Comment: Yes. How to make the for loop function. It must be standard JS. I don't use JQuery. I've come quite a bit further. This is the new progress: http://flamencopeko.net/ajax3. Do you think I should make a new thread? This is a bit far from the original subject, and especially the title. I will post all files and code of course. And explain in detail where I'm at.

Comment: Thanks. I started a new thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627049/ajax-to-skip-through-array

Comment: How is your new thread going, I was on my trip these days. Still any problem? By the way, did my answer do help? If yes, please remember to click “Mark as Answer”.

Comment: srain: I'm sorry. I didn't see this comment until now. The new thread was closed, I also see now. The problem is not resolved. But I do have a friend, he's not on this site, who is helping me. We kinda did get things to work. But him and I need to site down one day and really implement it, 'cos the test we have now is like, uhm, double code mess.

Answer (score 0):

please print your $arrayFiles array after the array_values() method and see what you are getting (proper array). These all methods work properly in PHP as expaling below

```
$people = array("Peter", "Joe", "Glenn", "Cleveland");

echo current($people) . "<br />";
echo next($people) . "<br />";
echo prev($people). "<br />";
echo end($people). "<br />";
echo reset($people). "<br />";

// result
Peter
Joe
Peter
Cleveland
Peter
```

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing now with `print_r(array_values($arrFiles));` ?

Comment: so what result are you getting when you do - print_r(array_values($arrFiles)); ??

Comment: I've marked that clearly on the page now. Too long to post here.